# Java LRUCache, why we need another collection

Tags: java, caching

I am going through this post to understand LRUCache in Java - [Java LRU cache using LinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055210/java-lru-cache-using-linkedlist)

There is a solution in this post :

```
public class LRUCache {

    private Map<Integer, Integer> blocks = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    private LinkedList<Integer> bru = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    private int capacity;
    private int length;

    public LRUCache(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.length = 0;
    }

    public int get(int key) {
        Integer value = blocks.get(key);
        if (value != null) {
            bru.remove(value);
            bru.addFirst(value);
            return value;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void set(int key, int value) {
        if (blocks.containsKey(key)) {
            bru.remove(blocks.get(key));
            blocks.put(key, value);
        } else {
            if (length >= capacity) {
                blocks.remove(bru.removeLast());
                length--;
            }

            length++;
            blocks.put(key, value);
        }
        bru.addFirst(value);
    }
}
```

In this program, `blocks` map is the actual one which holds the required values. then why we need the other collection `bru` LinkedList here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map<Integer, Integer> blocks` is the actual one which holds the required values,

while `LinkedList<Integer> bru` is used to store **recently visited** values.

Comment: Thanks, do we need length variable in the program? because we can use blocks.size() to know the length.

Comment: It's necessary. `blocks.size()` returns the current size, which is less or equals the `length`(capability)